# Selenium if driver.is_enabled(): doesn't work

Tags: javascript, css, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

Hi everyone I have a task to do some scrape job from [this link](http://www.felgenoutlet.at/en), the thing is I am trying by clicking to get to the final look of the page and that is table with some data, but sometimes it requires only one click and in the other hand it requires more than one. In that case I have tried by controlling with if statement in which I have said **if** element from final view of the page **is_enabled()**(I have tried also with **is_displayed()**) go to the function that prints out final page view. Please if you can help me because I don't how to solve this anymore. Here is my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementNotInteractableException
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import urllib.request
import re

ignored_exceptions=(NoSuchElementException,StaleElementReferenceException)
#Function that will do writing because I don't have these atrb in final page look as data
def write(make,model,body,nesto):
    source = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "lxml")
    table = soup.find('table')
    table_rows = table.find_all('tr')
    for tr in table_rows:
        td = tr.find_all('td')
        scrape_list = [make,model,body,td]
        print(scrape_list)


def not_normal():
    another_back = driver.find_element_by_class_name("btn btn-back pull-left kba_step_back")
    another_back.click()
    item_type_list = driver.find_element_by_class_name("kba_vehicle_type_group_id")
    item = item_type_list.find_element_by_tag_name("li")
    make = driver.find_element_by_class_name("make")
    model = driver.find_element_by_class_name("model")
    body = driver.find_element_by_class_name("body")
    item.click()
    another_back.click()
    write(make.text,model.text,body.text,item.text)
    while True:
        try:
            button_back = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "back")))
            button_back.click()
        except TimeoutException:
            break

driver = webdriver.Chrome("/home/cutie/Desktop/felgenoutlet/bin/chromedriver")
driver.get("https://www.felgenoutlet.com/en")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 3)
#Opens webpage

first_list = driver.find_element_by_class_name("kba_vehicle_trade_group_id")
wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.TAG_NAME,'li')))
cars = first_list.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")
for car in cars:
    car.click()
    try:
        final_view=driver.find_element_by_class_name("header_entry_list")
        if final_view.is_enabled():
            not_normal()
            continue
    except:
        print("not found", end='\n')
        second_list = driver.find_element_by_class_name("kba_vehicle_model_group_id")
        second_list_items= wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.TAG_NAME,'li')))

        second_list_items = second_list.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")
        for model in second_list_items:
            model.click()
            try:
                final_view=driver.find_element_by_class_name("header_entry_list")
                if final_view.is_enabled():
                    not_normal()
                    continue
            except:
                third_list = driver.find_element_by_class_name("kba_vehicle_body_group_id")
                third_list_items= wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.TAG_NAME,'li')))
                third_list_items = third_list.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")
                for body in third_list_items:
                    body.click()
                    try:
                        final_view=driver.find_element_by_class_name("header_entry_list")
                        if final_view.is_enabled():
                            not_normal()
                            continue
                    except:
                        fourth_list = driver.find_element_by_class_name("kba_vehicle_type_group_id")
                        fourth_list_items = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.TAG_NAME,'li')))
                        fourth_list_items = fourth_list.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")
                        for nesto in fourth_list_items:
                            make = driver.find_element_by_class_name("make").text
                            model = driver.find_element_by_class_name("model").text
                            body = driver.find_element_by_class_name("body").text
                            write(make,model,body,nesto.text)
                            nesto.click()
```

And here is my problematic if statement:

```
final_view=driver.find_element_by_class_name("header_entry_list")
                if final_view.is_enabled():
                    not_normal()
                    continue
```

Any help would be appreciated
**UPDATE PROBLEM SOLVED SOON CODE SOLUTION WILL BE UPLOADED**

Comment: What is `not_normal()` all about? Why do you need `final_view.is_enabled()`?

Comment: not_normal() is a function which I call when less than 4 clicks aren't displayed to so I could click on them, and final_view is selenium object which contains the element of final page look so if it's displayed I call a function not_normal()

Answer (score 1):

.isEnabled() method of selenium checks only for a disabled or enabled tag on the element. If the element does not have a disabled or enabled tag (i.e. div disabled="disabled"/div) then isEnabled() will not work for that element.

It looks like the element you're locating with classname "header_entry_list" is a table element, which doesnt have a disabled/enabled tag.

isDisplayed() checks for a width and height greater than 0 I believe, it will return true regardless of whether or not the element is visible in your viewport (like on your screen, scrolling down).

Maybe you can check for an element you expect to appear when you click the right amount of tries and use a boolean to handle repeated clicks.